# Что делает *this?

Tags: c++, указатели, this

Просто this, как я понял, возвращает ссылку на вызывающий объект. А что *this делает?
Я читал что разыменование указателя дает значение на который этот указатель указывает.

```
int a = 1
int *pa = &a
*pa == 1 true
```

Но *this вообще запутал

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1443667/edit) в метках язык программирования, на котором вы пишете.

Comment: `this` - указатель, не ссылка. `*` разыменовывает его, да.

Comment: Это во всяких java и c# this - ссылка, а в С++ - это указатель.

Comment: Разыменование не так работает. Вы получаете **объект/переменную** на который(ую) указывает указатель, **не** значение.

Answer (score 2):

Верно, что `*` - оператор разыменования, неверно, что `this` - ссылка.

`this` - *указатель* на текущий объект. Таким образом,
`*this` - *ссылка* на текущий объект.

Comment: `*this` - не ссылка, [выражения не бывают ссылками](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat строго говоря это glvalue-выражение, но в первом приближении удобнее думать про такие штуки как про ссылки

Comment: @PavelMayorov Еще точнее, lvalue. *"первом приближении удобнее"* Ну такое, потом придется переучиваться.

Answer (score 0):

Не путайтесь в выражениях. `this` - это указатель, **не ссылка**.
Когда вы используете `*this` вы как бы избавляетесь от посредника (указателя). И используете уже сам объект на который этот указатель указывает. Например: представим ситуацию, когда нам нужно вернуть **ссылку** на наш объект в методе. Тогда мы и будем использовать `*this`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class thisClass
{
public:
    thisClass& getThis() // thisClass& - это ссылка. А вот thisClass* - указатель.
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    thisClass myClass;
    thisClass& link = myClass.getThis();
    system("pause");
    return 1;
};
```

Если бы вы использовали `this` в этом случае, то вы бы не смогли даже скомпилировать этот код (В моём компиляторе).

Кстати: если вам плохо даётся понимание всех этих ссылок/указателей - почитайте про то, как устроена оперативная память в ПК. Мне это помогло разобраться во всём этом.

Answer (score -1):

На встроенных типах данных не очень понятно объяснять. Лучше на классах.
Когда у вас есть класс, в нем есть данные и методы. Из метода класса есть доступ к данным этого класса.

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
   int data;
   void method(void) { data++; }
}

int main()
{
  MyClass obj1, obj2;
  obj1.method();
}
```

Вы создали объект этого класса и вызываете метод. Как система узнаёт, что метод вызван для объекта obj1, а не для какого-то другого? Как в методе определить над какими данными нужно производит операции? Программист этого не видит, но в метод неявно передается указатель `this` для того объекта, для которого вызван метод. И доступ к данным идет относительно него.

```
void method(class MyClass* this) // на самом деле сигнатура метода выглядит вот так
// она компилятором генерируется автоматически!!! Самому так писать не надо!
{
  this->data++; // доступ к данным идет через указатель this
}
```

Когда вызывается метод для объекта, адрес этого объекта передается в метод, чтобы он мог оперировать данными именно этого объекта.
Если коротко, `this` - это указатель на текущий объект.

Comment: Но ведь автор просил объяснить, что такое ```*this```..